# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 : MqtUtil

Tags: c++, qt, maya, undefined-symbol

I try to compile a simple cpp Qt class for Maya, and get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MQtUtil::toMString(QString const&)", referenced from:
      MyMainWidgetClass::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*) in helixQtCmd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have this include:

```
#include <maya/MQtUtil.h>
```

and this code:

```
void MyMainWidgetClass::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    MGlobal::displayInfo(MQtUtil::toMString(e->text()));
}
```

but it fails at compilation. Any idea why ?

Comment: You have to have Qt built for Maya. Which Maya version are you using?

Comment: I am using Maya version 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was linked to a missing lib in the Makefile: OpenMayaUI.